# In excel, how can I format a raw so that the second number is in parentheses?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I have a row with the following numbers:

4 (8)   3.8 (12)    5 (7)   4.6 (35)    5 (8)   4.4 (27)    4.8 (104)   4.3 (38)    4.3 (2,634)     4.4 (54)    4.5 (90)    4.8 (156)   4.6 (297)   4.5 (26)    4 (6)   4.5 (719)   4.4 (213)   4.3 (615)       4.8 (636)   4.2 (322)   4.6 (150)

I'd rather write them like this:

4 8 3.8 12  5 7 4.6 35  5 8 4.4 27  4.8 104 4.3 38  4.3 2,634       4.4 54  4.5 90  4.8 156 4.6 297 4.5 26  4 6 4.5 719 4.4 213 4.3 615     4.8 636 4.2 322 4.6 150

Can I enter them into the cells without the parenthesis and format them at the end to add the parenthesis?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

Create a duplicate row under the first one and add the formula

```
=CONCATENATE("(",B1,")")
```

It will add the parenthesis on the value of B1

or second method to go pro, with the condition of one column with parenthesis one not go with:

> =IF((MOD(COLUMN(),2)),CONCATENATE("(",B1,")"),B1)

[image]

Comment: Alternative; use `TEXT("(0)",B1)` instead of `CONCATENATE(...)` - change "0" according to the number formatting rules in 'Custom formatting' (as in the CTRL+1 dialog) and you'll have them applied.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! One problem though... I have each set in one cell. Here's a screenshot of what I mean (its the top row): https://www.dropbox.com/s/p5byjtlumolwkb3/Screen%20Shot%202014-11-23%20at%208.35.37%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: @JacobMolloy if you could provide the image before! It would be more convenient for answering to the point. Anyway, you need a fixed condition for inserting brackets and you can achieve this by vba, but that should go to stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

If you only want this to affect the way the data is displayed, then instead of using a formula you can use conditional formatting. I can't think of a general solution that would bracket every other column, but you could bracket the second and then use the Format Painter to copy the first two columns' formatting across your data set:

Let's say you have data in columns starting from column A.

- Select column B, right-click and go to cell properties.
- Under the Number tab, in the Category subsection, select Custom.
- In the Type field, type `(General)` and click OK.
- Select columns A and B, and click the [Format Painter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/copy-formats-from-one-cell-or-range-to-another-HP005199434.aspx) icon from the ribbon.
- Drag the formatting across columns C through the end of your sheet. You could also paste this onto the entire worksheet if you want to, by using the triangular button left of column A, and above row 1.

That should alternate standard formatting and bracketed formatting on your spreadsheet.